# Can we side load our template in Windows Template Studio of VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-template-studio

I am using [**Windows Template Studio**](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio) in my **VS2017 Community Edition**. I can add different component as page. I am willing to know is there any way to side load our own custom component or page locally (offline). So the purpose is need to show my custom controls along with default controls.

Comment: What's exactly thing you want to custom? Project type, Framework or page? If you mean pages locally why  not just right click your project to add new items?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported but there's an open issue on the backlog for it https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/issues/234